# JGraphT: get neighbor nodes

Tags: java, graph, jgrapht

I have a simple undirected graph `G = (V, E)`. Given a node `n`, is there an easy way to find all its neighbors, i.e. all nodes `m`, such that `{n, m} in E`?

There's `edgesOf` method, which returns all edges connected to given node. However, it seems that in an undirected graph it's somewhat arbitrary, which node is the source and which is the target.

I guess I could simply check whether my node is the source or the target and then the other node is the neighbor I'm looking for, but that's clunky. Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: frequently going for the fancy solution without first demostrating a solution leads to the dumpsters

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Haven't I actually outlined one possible solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it through neighborListOf(Graph g, V vertex), e.g.:

```
    Graph<String, DefaultEdge> g = new SimpleGraph<>(DefaultEdge.class);

    String v1 = "v1";
    String v2 = "v2";
    String v3 = "v3";
    String v4 = "v4";

    g.addVertex(v1);
    g.addVertex(v2);
    g.addVertex(v3);
    g.addVertex(v4);

    g.addEdge(v1, v2);
    g.addEdge(v2, v3);
    g.addEdge(v3, v4);
    g.addEdge(v4, v1);

    System.out.println(Graphs.neighborListOf(g, v1));
```